# Grails criteria query checking `OR` logic

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I having grails `criteriaQuery` where I am checking `OR` logic againist a single state variable like this:

```
or {
     eq("status", Status.ONE)
     eq("status", Status.TWO)
     eq("status", Status.THREE)
  }
```

This code is working fine, My question is, as I am checking `OR` logic againist a single state, Is there any way to optimize this code like

```
 eq("status",Status.ONE || Status.TWO || Status.THREE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `'in'("status", [Status.ONE, Status.TWO, Status.THREE])` instead. Or just `'in'("status", Status.values())` if `Status` is an enum with values ONE, TWO & THREE.

Comment: @dmahapatro thank u I 'll try, I stuck in some other issue

Comment: @dmahapatro you can add your comment as answer, it is correct

Comment: @dmahapatro, you having any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812376/grails-difficultly-in-using-hibernate-onetomany-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
'in'( "status", [Status.ONE, Status.TWO, Status.THREE] )
```

Or just

```
'in'( "status", Status.values() )
```

if `Status` is an enum with values ONE, TWO & THREE.