# Grails difficultly in using Hibernate OneToMany model

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

In my new project I am trying to use Hibernate model class, here one `user` domain class having `OneToMany` relation `userProfile` like

```
class User {
    //Some fields and getter setter

    //Problematic thing
    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(mappedBy = "User")
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles;

    //getter is like
    public Set<userProfile> getProfile() {
       // the logic
    }
    public void setProfile() {
       // the logic
    }

}
```

So when I try to access this field in grails criteria like

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
    List<User> userList = criteria.list() {
        userProfiles {
            eq("id",1 as long)
        }
    }
```

I getting the error like `No signature of method: UserService.userProfiles()`. I think it might be because of different `getter` and `setter` name, 'cause for remaining `OneToMany` fields the `criteria` is working fine.

Is there any possible and standard way to address this issue.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem but there are several funky things in your code.  Why aren't you using http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html ? Instead of `Set<userProfile>` you probably want `Set<UserProfile>` as I assume the class name is `UserProfile`. You have a `setProfile()` method which returns a `Set` and you also have a `setProfile()` method which returns `void`. You cannot overload methods by changing only the return type. I expect that one of those is supposed to be `getProfile` and the other is probably should accept a `Set<UserProfile>` as an argument.

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown, I done a mistake in `getter` and `setter`, see my edit, but here I can't use hasMany, 'cause we are supposed to use `hibernate` models

Comment: "I can't use hasMany, 'cause we are supposed to use hibernate models" - You are allowed to use `hasMany` with hibernate models.  That is very common.

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown,Ohhh thank you for new info. Anyway We can't edit that file, we forced to go only with existing things

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown, is their any possible way to call `getProfile() { eq("id",1 as long)  }`, I tried this it is show throwing `No signature of method` exception

Comment: "is their any possible way to call `getProfile() { eq("id",1 as long)  }`" - Yes, if you define a method named `getProfile` which accepts a `groovy.lang.Closure` as an argument and then in the method you used that `Closure` as an argument to `withCriteria` or similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61127/discussion-between-suganthan-and-jeff-scott-brown).

Answer (score 0):

This is a more common thing to do:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [userProfiles: UserProfile]
}
```

Methods like `getUserProfiles()`, `setUserProfiles()`, `addToUserProfiles(UserProfile p)` etc. are automatically generated.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html.

Then you could do something like this:

```
def userList = User.withCriteria {
    userProfiles {
        idEq 1
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You are right, But I can't use this hasMany stuffs, only because we supposed to use `Hibernate Model`.

Comment: "You are right, But I can't use this hasMany stuffs, only because we supposed to use Hibernate Model" - `hasMany` can be used with a Hibernate model.  That is very common.